# How do I use a Portable CDI Extension in an EAR on JBoss AS7?

Tags: jboss, cdi, ear

We have a web application WAR that includes portable CDI extensions (seam-spring-core, activity-cdi) as JARs in the WEB-INF/lib, which works as expected on JBoss AS7.1.1.

However, when we package the WAR in an EAR the service discovery mechanism seams to fail. The class loader does not find the respective resource files in META-INF/services any more.

We have tried to put the portable CDI extensions into (JBoss) modules, however this stops the CDI annotations from being processed. We have also tried to put the JARs inside the EAR's lib directory, with the same result.

Where is the right place for portable CDI extensions within an EAR? Should portable CDI extensions within the WAR work - as it does without the EAR? Is this a JBoss AS7.1.1 issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should work (jars in ear's lib) do you have beans.xml in ear? It's possible it's needed to dice into the jars.

Comment: You're right the CDI extensions are discovered when I put them into the EAR's lib folder. However, I've problems to get them working as expected. The CDI extensions now operate in the context of the EAR. The WAR seems to have a different context (BeanManager).

Comment: Isn't there a possibility to have the CDI extension available in the context of the WAR?

Comment: The way the BDA (Bean Descriptor Archive) works is that you'd need the extension in the war (and possibly in the EAR as well). At this point, I'd ask why the constraint of it being in an EAR?

Comment: If I put the extension into the WAR, it's simply not discovered.